# Let H be the orthocenter of the sharp triangle ABC

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $H$ be the orthocenter of acute triagle $ABC$. On the single direction $(HA$, $(HB$ and $(HC$ is considered
points $D$, $E$ and $F$ such that:
$HD = BC$, $HE = AC$ and $HF = AB$.

Let it be shown that:[image]

1. if $M$, $N$ and $P$ are the midpoint$[BC]$, $[CA]$ and $[AB]$, then: $DE = 2CP$, $EF = 2AM$ and $DF = 2BN$.
2. $H$ is the center of gravity of the triangle $DEF$.

Comment: A drawing were here very useful. Particularly it is not clear what "semicircle $(HA$" means.

Comment: I really don't know how to draw a picture and put it here

Comment: In the worst case you can draw picture by hand on a sheet of paper, make a photo, and insert it into the body of your message (Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V).

Comment: @CalvinLin yes to all

Comment: What have you tried? Angle chasing? Side length chasing?

Comment: It's a pretty direct question. I encourage you to draw the diagram, label the points, angles, and side lengths.

Comment: It is nice that you have added a figure. However it does not contain any points of $D,E,F,M,N,P$. Thus the figure adds absolutely nothing to the statement "$H$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove first part with the law of cosine. Let $BC = a$, $CA = b$ and $AB = c$. If $\angle ACB = x$, then we have (observe triangle $DEH$):

\begin{align}
ED^2 & =  a^2+b^2-2ab\cos (180-x) \\
& =  a^2+b^2+2ab \cos x\\
& =  a^2+b^2 +(a^2+b^2-c^2)\\
& =  2a^2+2b^2-c^2
\end{align}

On the other hand we have (observe triagle $BCP$)
\begin{eqnarray}
CP^2 & = & a^2+{c^2\over 4}-2a{c\over 2}\color{\red}{\cos (\beta) }\\
& = & a^2+{c^2\over 4}-ac \color{\red}{a^2+c^2-b^2\over 2ac}\\
& = &...\\
& = & {2a^2+2b^2-c^2\over 4}\\
& = & {ED^2\over 4}
\end{eqnarray}
For red relation observe the triangle $ABC$

Comment: I think in the same way we proceed to find out the other two relations

Comment: Of course........

Comment: To clarify, the algebra works out because (see my image) $\triangle CBT = \triangle EHD$.

Answer (score 0):

Main hint: Construct point T such that $CBTA$ is a parallelogram. Then, $2CP = CT$.

**Hint to 1:** Angle chase + Side chase triangle $HDE$.
Show that this is congruent to another triangle involving $CT$.
Hence conclude that $ DE = CT = 2CP$.

> $\triangle HDE \sim \triangle BTC$ so $DE =  TC = 2CP$.

**Hint to 2:** Let midpoint of $DE$ be $X$. Angle chase + Side chase triangle $EHX$.
Show that this triangle is congruent to another triangle involving $CP$.
Hence conclude that $ EHX$ is a straight line.

> $\triangle EHX \sim \triangle CBP $. Actually, this is just the previous triangle, using the midpoint on $DE$ and $CT$. Hence, $\angle EHX  = \angle BAC $, so $EHX$ is a straight line.

Corollary: Since $EX$ is the median, so $H$ is the centroid of $DEF$.

---

Diagram not drawn to scale because I was too lazy to ensure $HD=BC$.

[image]

Comment: does not seem very true

Comment: Which particular part does not seem true?

Comment: now I understand, thank you

Comment: The point $H$ in the figure does not look like the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: Right, I uploaded the wrong image, fixed.

Comment: I would certainly upvote your answer if you make it complete. Now, it is rather difficult to follow, especially without seeing the congruent triangles in the figure.

Comment: Thanks. I don't particularly care about upvotes (esp for this question). This is very easy to push through, if you do minimal work of labelling side lengths and angles you see it come out, which is the point i'm making.

Comment: It is a pity. Because I am sure that the answers should be helpful not only for the asking person but for all people including those who will just list your answer. And I am sure if it is written in more clear way it will be useful for a plenty of people.

Comment: I totally understand. However, I get contradictory messages from MSE about what the "solution" should accomplish. I've been insulted for providing complete details when "OP didn't show any work" because "we want to avoid this becoming a homework site" (which arguably this case falls under), and was told explicitly that "If you don't believe in spoon-feeding, do not do that here". So, I'm slowly becoming indifferent, writing up solutions the way I want to. IE If it says "hint", then expect to do some work.

Comment: I am very sorry about this policy of MSE. Especially considering the fact, that a person who does not want to work out his/her homework properly always find a mean to avoid this. And here a possibility to learn more about beauty of geometry went to waste.

Comment: Alright, I've included the triangles as a rollover.